# Diffusion coefficient for acid base reaction

Tags: diffusion

I am trying to model an acid-base neutralization reaction.  There are two adjacent slabs - one acid and one base. Each slab is the same thickness and I'm only looking at one-dimensional diffusion/reaction.  At time $t = 0$, the acid slab has a concentration of cA0 throughout and the base slab has a concentration of cB0 throughout.  At $t>0$ diffusion occurs and reaction occurs at an interface between the two slabs.  In general cA0 is greater than cB0 and therefore A penetrates into the B slab; in other words the reaction plane is a moving boundary.

I have an analytical expression for the concentration profiles that appears to work very well based on comparisons with MatLab simulations.  However, it was developed assuming a constant value for the diffusion coefficient, D, for both acid and base. But, in reality, the diffusion coefficients are different.  Is there a weighted or average or calculated diffusion coefficient that I could use that would apply to both acid and base?  I've tried just using an average, but now the results of the analytical expression are noticeably different than the MatLab simulation.  Maybe an average isn't the right way to do this.

Also, which diffusion coefficient for each species should I use?  Let's say acid is HCL and base NaOH. Should I start with a coefficient for hydrogen ion and one for hydroxide ion?  Or should it be a D for the HCL molecule and the NaOH molecule?  Or.......

Comment: Are you serious about HCl and NaOH molecules in water solutions ? // Generally, Ds for particular ions will differ significantly for thick solutions very different to water. Their values are highly empirical.

Comment: In solution HCl and NaOH don't exist as molecules but only as ions, $H^+, OH^-$ so you need to find diff'n coefficients for these. You will also need to include chemical reaction in your equations for the equilibrium to form water molecules.  The rate constants for this are known via T jump relaxation experiments, have a look in a phys chem text book.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean molecules exactly.  If charge separation is to be prevented doesn't that mean that even though $H^+$ has a significantly higher value of D than $Cl^-$, it will be slowed down and $Cl^-$ will speed up.  Any comments on my question about possibly using an "average" or "weighted" diffusivity for both reactants?

Comment: @porphyrin.  Strictly speaking I should include the equilibrium with water.  It means that $OH^-$ will never be exactly zero, which is what my models assume at the reaction interface (i.e. instantaneouus reaction where A and B cannot coexist). But ultimately I am trying to determine the time for neutralization starting with an $OH^-$ concentration of $10^{-2}$.  So five orders of magnitude reduction is "effectively" complete reaction.  Any thoughts on use of an "average" or "weighted" diffusivity?

Comment: You could use an average value, but would it not be better to have equations for the diffusion of each species coupled with the $H^+ + OH^- = H_2O$ equilibrium and solve at each time and spatial step? Alternatively, as an approximation  assume  $D_H$ is  v large and equilib instantaneous so the process is effectively determined by relatively slowly diffusing OH$^-$

Comment: I am having difficulty determining what values for the diffusion coefficients I should use.  Any guidance is appreciated.